# AngularJS parser is not activatied when application name is provided

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Using AngularJS, the following html code prints {{1+1}} instead of 2

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <script src="/js/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
{{1+1}}
</body>
</html>
```

While if I remove "myApp" like below, it prints 2 correctly.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app>
<head>
    <script src="/js/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
{{1+1}}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: My question is why the first one is not working.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because you don't specify the module `myApp` so it blows up on the error.

Open web inspector console to see it.

```
// adding this will fix it
angular.module('myApp', []);
```